# Problem with "while" in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm trying out several exercises from a Java programming book. I have the code below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex420
{
 public static void main( String args[] )
 {
  String employeeName = "";
  double workHours,excessHours, hourlyRates, grossPay;
  Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

  while ( employeeName != "stop" )
  {
   System.out.printf( "\nInput employee name or stop to exit: " );
    employeeName = input.nextLine();
   System.out.printf( "Input working hours: " );
    workHours = input.nextDouble();
   System.out.printf( "Input hourly rates: " );
    hourlyRates = input.nextDouble();

   if ( workHours <= 40 & workHours >= 0 )
   {
    excessHours = 0;
    grossPay = hourlyRates * workHours;
    System.out.printf( "%s's gross pay is $%.2f\n", employeeName, grossPay );
   }
   else if ( workHours > 40 )
   {
    excessHours = workHours - 40;
    grossPay = hourlyRates * 40 + 1.5 * hourlyRates * excessHours;
    System.out.printf( "\n%s's worked for %.1f excess hours.\n", employeeName, excessHours );
    System.out.printf( "%s's gross pay is $%.2f\n", employeeName, grossPay ); 
   }
   else
   {
    System.out.printf( "Invalid input. Please try again." );
   }  
  } // end while
 } // end main
} // end class Ex420
```

The problem is, the while loop doesn't seem to be working. Whenever I input "stop" as the employeeName, the program just goes on. I tried replacing "stop" with any other String and it still doesn't work. But when I try initializing employeeName with "stop", the program quits right away, which is expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Furthermore, after the first loop, the program always skips asking the employeeName. I tried replacing `employeeName = input.nextLine();` with `employeeName = input.next();` and it doesn't skip it anymore. I'm wondering though, is there any way I can make it not skip the input when using `employeeName = input.nextLine();`?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because the `!=` test you use in the `while` loop compares strings for reference equality. That is, when it makes a comparison, it's not just testing to see whether the strings have the same sequence of characters; it checks to see if they are *the exact same object*. But when the `Scanner` creates a `String` to contain the text it read from standard input, that `String` is not going to be the same object as the string literal `"stop"` in your code. They're two objects that just happen to have the same content, but they exist at different locations in memory, so `!=` treats them as being unequal.

Solution: start your loop like this instead:

```
while (!"stop".equals(employeeName)) {
```

Answer (score 13):

When comparing strings in Java use equals method, not == or != operators. By using those operators you simply compare references to objects and not their contents. So your condition should look like

```
while ( !"stop".equals(employeeName) )
```

Note the that "stop" is first because theoretically your employeeName variable can be null. This way the code is not going to throw `NullPointerException` by calling equals method on the null object.

Comment: You probably mean `while (!"stop".equals(employeeName))` to match the meaning of the example code, right?

Comment: I like the 'Yoda' expression :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're not using the right structure and you need to use `equals()` not `==` to compare `String`s. The basic structure you want is:

```
System.out.printf("\nInput employee name or stop to exit: ");
String employeeName = input.nextLine();
while (!employeeName.equals("stop")) {
  ...
  System.out.printf("\nInput employee name or stop to exit: ");
  employeeName = input.nextLine();
}
```

Basically you need to check if the user entered "stop" immediately and the above does that. Your version doesn't.

On a side note, try and adopt Java coding conventions including spacing and curly brace placement.

Comment: Thanks for the input about the while loop and the programming conventions! I didn't realize my spacing and placement is different from it.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto previous posters on == versus equals.

It works when you initialize employeeName to "stop" because the Java compiler sees two identical strings and re-used the object. That is:

String employeeName="stop";
   if (employeeName=="stop")
   ... etc ...

The test evaluates to true because Java creates an object to hold the first string, then it notices that the second string is identical so it re-uses the object, and thus the == comparison is comparing an object to itself.

But if instead you read the employeeName from the keyboard or a file, now the compiler of course doesn't know what someone will type in, a new object is created to hold this value, and an == compare between two different string objects returns false.